# Vue, Disable all other inputs after radio is clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I loop over an array and display a list of radio buttons. I am trying to disable all other radio inputs except for the one selected after one is clicked. All I have been able to manage is to disable all of the radios or the one that is clicked.

I was able to accomplish dynamically adding a class in the `v-for` loop, so I tried disabling the inputs in the same manner, but everything gets disabled:

```
:disabled="{'disabled':answer.answerID == isChecked}"
```

I also tried using a method, but didn't have any luck there either:

/* List data */

```
"answers":[
      {
        "answerID": "1",
        "answerName": "Blueberries"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "2",
        "answerName": "Apples"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "3",
        "answerName": "Bananas"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "4",
        "answerName": "Pineapple"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "5",
        "answerName": "Strawberries"
      }
  ]
```

/* Component code */

```
<template>
    <input
        v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
        :key="index"
        type="radio"
        class="mg-input mg-answer"
        ref="mgAnswer"
        name="mg-answer"
        :value="answer.answerName"
        v-model="answerVal"
        :disabled="disableAnswer(answers, index)"
        :class="{'mg-checked':answer.answerID == isChecked}"
        @click="
          isChecked = answer.answerID
          checkAnswer(answers, index, $event)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      // Class definer for is checked or not
      isChecked: undefined,
      // Answer Data Properties
      answerVal: '',
      checkedAnswerID: '',
      checkedAnswerElem: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkAnswer: function (arr, i, event) {
      let mgAnswer = this.$refs.mgAnswer
      this.checkedAnswerID = arr[i].answerID
      this.checkedAnswerElem = mgAnswer[i]

      if (mgAnswer[i].answerName !== this.answerVal) {
        this.answerVal = ''
      }
    },
    disableAnswer: function (arr, i) {
      if (arr[i].answerName !== this.answerVal) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, I am using v-model with data variable answerVal, I have tried using.  ```:disabled="!answerVal[index]"``` this disables all inputs, and something like ```:disabled="answerVal[index] && isChecked ? true : false" ``` but again it is either all of them or just the one clicked, I need the ones that are not clicked to be disabled.

Comment: When I select an input with v-model="[index]" I get an error, Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value:, Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in

Comment: As an aside, isn't that a problematic UX? What about an accidental selection?

Comment: What if someone clicks a radio button. So he can't click any other because all are disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disableAnswer(answers, index)` is evaluated only once upon rendering. Initially, `answerVal` is `null`, as no answers have been selected yet, so `disableAnswer` returns `true`, causing all radio buttons to be disabled immediately.

A quick fix is to add `answerVal` as a function argument (i.e., `disableAnswer(answers, index, answerVal)`), so that the function is re-evaluated when `answerVal` changes. We have to also modify `disableAnswer` to ignore `null` values of `answerVal`, which would occur at initialization:

```
disableAnswer(arr, i, answerVal) {
  if (!answerVal) {
    // not yet set
    return;
  }

  if (arr[i].answerName !== answerVal) {
    return true
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      // Class definer for is checked or not
      isChecked: undefined,
      // Answer Data Properties
      answerVal: '',
      checkedAnswerID: '',
      checkedAnswerElem: '',
      "answers":[
        {
          "answerID": "1",
          "answerName": "Blueberries"
        },
        {
          "answerID": "2",
          "answerName": "Apples"
        },
        {
          "answerID": "3",
          "answerName": "Bananas"
        },
        {
          "answerID": "4",
          "answerName": "Pineapple"
        },
        {
          "answerID": "5",
          "answerName": "Strawberries"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkAnswer: function (arr, i, event) {

      let mgAnswer = this.$refs.mgAnswer
      this.checkedAnswerID = arr[i].answerID
      this.checkedAnswerElem = mgAnswer[i]

      if (mgAnswer[i].answerName !== this.answerVal) {
        this.answerVal = ''
      }
    },

    disableAnswer: function (arr, i, answerVal) {
      if (!answerVal) return;
      if (arr[i].answerName !== answerVal) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;

  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;

  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

input[disabled] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.mg-checked {
  border: 6px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input
        v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
        :key="index"
        type="radio"
        class="mg-input mg-answer"
        ref="mgAnswer"
        name="mg-answer"
        :value="answer.answerName"
        v-model="answerVal"
        :disabled="disableAnswer(answers, index, answerVal)"
        :class="{'mg-checked':answer.answerID == isChecked}"
        @click="
          isChecked = answer.answerID
          checkAnswer(answers, index, $event)" />
  
  {{answerVal}}
</div>
```

---

<sup>*You might also find useful a minor refactoring of your code: [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QBYKGZ)*</sup>

Comment: Awesome thank you. That worked. Thank you so much for your help! I tried to refactor using your code however I could not get it to work properly but Option 1 sure did though!

Comment: @blicker No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

check if input is clicked or if not clicked in that case make disabled set to false.

```
<input :disabled="disableAnswer(answer)" />
```

Js

```
disableAnswer : function(answer){

 if(this.answerVal=="" ||this.answerVal==answer.answerName) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
     }

}
```

Added Snippet:

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
        answerVal:"",
        answers:[
      {
        "answerID": "1",
        "answerName": "Blueberries"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "2",
        "answerName": "Apples"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "3",
        "answerName": "Bananas"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "4",
        "answerName": "Pineapple"
      },
      {
        "answerID": "5",
        "answerName": "Strawberries"
      }
  ]

        
        },
        methods: {
           disableAnswer(item){
            if(this.answerVal=="" ||this.answerVal==item) {
             return false;
           } else {
             return true;
           }

        }
  
        }
        
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
<input
        v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
        :key="index"
        type="radio"
        class="mg-input mg-answer"
        ref="mgAnswer"
        name="mg-answer"
        :value="answer.answerName"
        v-model="answerVal"
        :disabled="disableAnswer(answer.answerName)"
       />
 

</div>
```